# Code to get if Background Data Restrition is enabled in android 6

Tags: android

i've making a file transfer app. i am using download manager in this. if backgroud data restriction is enabled, the transfers are being queued by the download manager.

i want to warn the user that file transfer doenst work if it is enabled.

is there a way to know if background data restriction is enabled programatically?
I want this to happen even in Android Marshmallow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390930/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-data-saver-is-enabled

Comment: @simon5678 thanks for the response. ive already seen that but it didnt work in marsmallow..  the app crashes as soon as i open it

Comment: Please add the crash log.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this, (I am new to android development) can you please tell me where can I find it. I've never had any use with it till now...

Comment: An for your information, I'm using AIDE

Comment: And while using the code that you have previously mentioned, I get an error "Unknown Variable or field RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_ENABLED"  i get the similar error for the other two cases also. should i declare it as public static final int?

Comment: See https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.net.ConnectivityManager&method=RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_ENABLED  . These variables are from ```ConnectivityManager``` class.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try them and let you know

Comment: Hey, I checked the one you told me. They all are dedicated to android versions above Nougat

Comment: And in marshmallow, the code isActiveMetworkMetered() is working. But the rest aren't working...

Comment: any other **ideas** ?

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for my phone of Android 10 .

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public boolean checkBackgroundDataRestricted() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        Log.i("test","getRestrictBackgroundStatus ="+connMgr.getRestrictBackgroundStatus());
        switch (connMgr.getRestrictBackgroundStatus()) {
            case ConnectivityManager.RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_ENABLED:
                // Background data usage and push notifications are blocked for this app
                return true;

            case ConnectivityManager.RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_WHITELISTED:
            case ConnectivityManager.RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_DISABLED:
                // Data Saver is disabled or the app is whitelisted
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know how that works in android 6. But play store warns me that background data restriction is enabled